# Running an email server on a VPN client, wanting traffic passed through for smtp, pop3,imap etc from vpn server.

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port, centos6, forwarding

I have a home broadband network which I also run an email server. As my provider won't give me a fixed ip address, and most servers refuse to accept smtp mail from dynamic ip ranges, I felt the simple solution we'd be to run a VPN between a virtual server I already have and my email box.

I've done that fine, I installed openvpn and that connection is fine.  My home network runs on 192.168.1.x,the vpn runs on 10.8.0.x with the client (my mail server)  having the address 10.8.0.6 on its end of the tunnel.  The vps has a real world ip address on the Internet side.

I ip forwarding enabled and I can happily send traffic out from the client, email, web browse etc, but I'm at a loss with how to forward traffic from the Internet on the smtp, imap, pop3 etc ports inbound to my mail server.

I hope I've given enough information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all ports:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d $real_world_ip -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d 10.8.0.6 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.x
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -d 10.8.0.6 -j ACCEPT
```

**Edit 1** (comment answering)

It is possible to make the mail server see the original address (this is trivial, you just have to leave out the SNAT rule). The challenge is to get the reply packets back to the vserver. You need advanced routing for this. And I guess you also need the Netfilter connection mark. You mark all new connections from the vserver, copy the connection mark to the packet mark and use the packet mark for the routing decision. You need define an additional routing table in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables. You could name it to_vserver.

The iptables block for each port, the others just once.

```
# mark new connections from VPN interface
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 42
# set packet mark of outgoing locally created packets which have this connection mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 42 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

# in this routing table: send everything over the VPN
ip route add table to_vserver 10.8.0.x dev tun0 src  10.8.0.6
ip route add table to_vserver default via 10.8.0.x

# use routing table to_vserver (instead of main) for every packet with this packet mark
ip rule add fwmark 42 priority 100 table to_vserver
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working.  I assume it's never going to be possible to have the original ip address appear to the smtp server, at the moment I'm getting the vpn server address on all the incoming connections.

Comment: @Hermit I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All Traffic to run thru the vpn
Here is the proper Windows 7 & dd-wrt set-up

Server Config:

```
server 172.20.20.0 255.255.255.248
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
dev tun0
proto tcp
port 443
keepalive 15 30

daemon
verb 0
mute 5
comp-lzo
duplicate-cn
tls-server

dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
tls-auth /tmp/openvpn/ta.key 0

management localhost 14
```

Client Config:

```
client
dev tun0
proto tcp
port 443
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
```

DD-wrt Firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 172.20.20.0/29 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Can you edit your answer to provide a brief explanation of how your answer addresses the OP's question for those who may not immediately recognize it from your posted config?

Answer (score -1):

VPN's do not change your public ip, let me repeat that vpn's do not obscure your real ip from your home ip, unless you are connected to an outside vpn meaning it isn't your home vpn. I have all my traffic successfully running thru my home dd-wrt vpn with the config I posted earlier. Email, browser's etc..

With out any port forwarding or port triggers, vpns are for security, vpns encrypt your data channels they don't hide or obscure your ip. You would need a proxy for that task or use tor browser thru your vpn for added security.

The public has a misconception & think vpns some how change your public ip they do not, a vpn assigns ip's like a regular router would, but now your data channel is encrypted and you can tunnel thru an open wifi securely to your home or office network. On the open wi-fi at some location your ip would be useing your home ip, and not the public wi-fi ip. I hope the public understands now.

Comment: That's wrong in many/most use cases of a VPN, and it's you with the misconception. Most (not all) VPN connections will change the apparent source of your network traffic, in other words, change your public IP for remote systems. Some don't or only for certain destinations, but that's dependent on the configuration of the VPN.